# Pyspark Dataframe Insert with overwrite and having more then one partitions

Tags: postgresql, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I'm having dataframe with 2 partitions, inserting into postgres table with overwrite method.

```
df.write \
    .format("jdbc") \
    .option("driver", POSTGRESQL_DRIVER) \
    .option("url", url) \
    .option("user", user) \
    .option("password", password) \
    .option("dbtable", "test_table") \
    .mode("overwrite") \
    .save()
```

Partitions Vector : (0, 1)

Partition 0 will insert first followed by partition 1, here partition 0 records are over writing in table. Only partition 1 records are available.

How can i insert or save two partitions without overwrite of previous partitions ?

Comment: how about using `append` mode instead of overwrite?

Comment: i don't want old data

Answer (score 1):

I can see below two possible workarounds for this problem.

1) As part of the write provide one more option to truncate the table and then append so that old data will be truncated and new data frame will be appended. Every time you will have only new dataset this way.

```
df.write \
    .format("jdbc") \
    .option("driver", POSTGRESQL_DRIVER) \
    .option("url", url) \
    .option("user", user) \
    .option("password", password) \
    .option("dbtable", "test_table") \
    .option("truncate", True) \
    .mode("append") \
    .save()
```

2) As part of the spark 2.3 we got new option where we can truncate only specific partition instead of all partitions. If you are using the latest version of spark, you can give try of this feature.

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-20236

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for suggestion @user805. 

I tried first one and getting twice record insert.  

df.count = 10 but table count = 20

Comment: which version of spark you are using? As per the JIRA ticket this is available in 2.1 version https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-16463

Comment: I'm using spark version 2.4.3